# android - How to restart the tab from another tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost

My application have two tabs: `tab1` and `tab2`. Initially `tab1` is activated. In this tab we have chance to navigate to child activities (In the sense `tab1` have initial activity (A1) that consists of one button if you click on that then it will redirects to `Activity2`..).

Now to you tap on the `tab2` and it have one button if you click on that then I want to restart the `tab1`. It means it shows the `tab1` with initial activity (A1). How to implement this. I tried but I am not getting.

Code:

```
//This will just activate the tab1. it's not reset

CustomTabActivity.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onClickListener` of button in Tab2 add the following code

```
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(String name of Tab1));
```

Comment: It will similar to my code. it just activate the tab1. But i want to reset the tab1. In sense tab1 starts from actvity1 onwords.

Comment: i wrote the above code in tab2 button click listener but it still activate the tab not restart it

Comment: Brother very difficult to help you without looking at your code.